# Hide placeholder text from dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hide the placeholder text in a dropdown menu from showing up as a selectable option.  I have searched other options on stack overflow and tried the following solution but none have worked:

```
<option style="display:none" >Select Stop</option>
<option value="" disabled selected hidden >Select Stop</option>
<option value="" disabled selected style="display: none;">Select Stop</option>
```

My code looks like this which WORKS in stackoverflow but not when I put it into my site using latest version of chrome...

```html
<select>
  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Stop</option>
  <option value="home">home</option>
  <option value="school">school</option>
  <option value="office">office</option>
</select>
```

Comment: why not simply remove it then ?

Comment: I need the placeholder text in there for UI clarity.

Comment: You just have a random value selected by default, some stuff ain't really worth the headache.

Comment: Maybe is from you'r website if there is working and i'm the latest google chrome. Check in the style tab if the option have "display: block;". If you have the disabled and hidden not working.

Comment: if I have it on display:block what should I change it too?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what are you actually trying achieve, to hide the select or option simply add disabled to them, see below, i have 2 select, one with option disbaled other one the entire select disabled

```html
        <select>
            <option value="">Select Stop</option>
   <option value="home" >home</option>
   <option value="school" disabled>school</option>
   <option value="office" >office</option>
        </select>

      <select disabled>
            <option value="" >Select Stop</option>
   <option value="home" >home</option>
   <option value="school" >school</option>
   <option value="office" >office</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Hi Jismon, Thank you for your response.  I am trying to hide the placeholder text "e.g. Select Stop" from showing up in the dropdown as an option.

Comment: Hi, you cannot do anything to the option tag other than disabling it, you cannot style option neither by inline or css

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you might want to add some JQuery into your file

```js
 $(function() {
            $('.location').find('option:contains(office)').hide();
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='location'>
  <option value="select stop">Select Stop</option>
  <option value="home">home</option>
  <option value="school">school</option>
  <option value="office">office</option>
</select>
```